# retrievePeripherals deprecated in IOS7 how to substitude it with retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `"[self.manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];”` which works fine but is deprecated in IOS7. I found I have to use “`retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers`” instead. But I can not figure out which would be the right syntax for the new function. Can anyone please translate

```
"[self.manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];”
```

to the new function “retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers”.

```
// Invoked when the central discovers heart rate peripheral while scanning.
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral
  advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
               RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSMutableArray *peripherals = [self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"heartRateMonitors"];
    if(![self.heartRateMonitors containsObject:aPeripheral])
    [peripherals addObject:aPeripheral];

    // Retrieve already known devices
[self.manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)aPeripheral.UUID]];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it, hope it helps.

```
// Invoked when the central discovers heart rate peripheral while scanning.
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral
  advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
               RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
[self.manager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]]];

NSLog(@"centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral -> Discovered: %@", aPeripheral.name);

if (aPeripheral) {
    [self stopScan];
    _peripheral = aPeripheral;
    [_manager connectPeripheral:self.peripheral
                        options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                                                            forKey:
                                 CBConnectPeripheralOptionNotifyOnDisconnectionKey]];
}


}
```

Comment: Just a quick note, this code will only retrieve devices with hearth rate services implemented

Comment: I think NSUUID should be used instead of CBUUID in order to identify peripherals. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749655/2610888. In the docs retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers takes an array od NSUUID https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanager/1519127-retrieveperipheralswithidentifie